# MacBook Pro Late 2011 doesn't upgrade further than 10.13.1

Tags: macos, software-update

In the App Store > Updates it showed the 10.13.4 update, I did that but **About this Mac** still shows me 10.13.1.

I would like to download the newest XCode but that reqiures at least 10.13.2
So I went to the Apple download page where it says I should upgrade it in the App store instead of installing it from scrap.
I tried through terminal, it downloaded and installed it, then it said I need to restart and wanted the password. After I typed in the password, the computer shut down and restarted. In the Terminal it said Session restarted, and the MacBook still runs on 10.13.1.
I have 210GB of free storage at the moment.

What could it be? Which further information can I provide to be more precise?
Is it not possible with my model? Is there an older version of XCode I could download?
I am thankful for any tip.

Comment: To clarify, did you try to update using Apple.com's downloads page? Specifically the 10.13.2 combo update here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1946

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I did an Internet Recovery and installed the Mac OS from scrap, respectively with cmd + alt + R to have the newest version installed. Finally worked.